# What is the expected value of the numbers of calls for a survey?

Tags: probability

I was asked the following question by a medical doctor:

He is working on a survey. Assume that he called 120 persons and 24 persons agreed to do the survey. The second time, he called 57 persons among those who refused the first time and 10 persons agreed to do the survey. What is the expected value of the number of phone calls for people to agree to do the survey?

I first thought it would be

$$\frac{24\times 1+10\times 2}{120}.$$

Then I thought it would be

$$\frac{24}{120}\times 1+\frac{10}{57}\times 2.$$

I am confused by these two ideas. I prefer the second computation. Please enlighten me. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: The question is not clear.  What do we do with the people who declined twice (or who were never called the second time)?  Or are you only interested in the conditional probability (conditioned, that is, on the assumption that the person eventually agrees)?

Comment: Just to say, note that your second method yields $.55$ which is obviously not what you intend.

Comment: My guess is that you want the conditional probability, but this is really not clear.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am also confused about the question. I will ask the doctor again. Best.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what exactly is the question and what are the assumptions regarding the population and their willingness to participate in the survey. Here is my approach, which might not be exactly what OP wants.

I assume that each person has a fixed probability $p$ to agree, regardless of the number of phone calls. This is constant for all people and that the $57$ people were chosen at random. Then, the number of calls until someone agrees to participate has a Geometric distribution with parameter $p$, and the average number of calls needed is $1/p$.

It is left to evaluate $p$. Based on the data, $24$ people agreed on the first call, $10$ on the second call, $47$ didn't agree on the first two calls (so $X\geq 3$ for them) and $39$ people didn't agree on the first call (so $X\geq 2$ for them).
The likelihood function is therefore
$$L(p)=p^{24} \times [(1-p)p]^{10}\times {(1-p)^2}^{39}\times {(1-p)^3}^{47}$$
The maximum of this function for $p\in (0,1)$ is at $p=\tfrac{34}{263}$ so the expected number of calls for a person to agree is $\tfrac{263}{34}=7.7$

Sanity check: in the first round, the success rate was fifth, so the expectation based on that should be around $5$. The people that didn't agree twice pull the success rate down, increasing the expected number of phonecalls.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation. I will discuss this with the doctor.